# Don't get wanted color of xml android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i'm trying to set the color of my text in gold for my scoreboard. I tried the following but it doens't work. I dont get any errors but the color hasn't changed. Any ideas why ?

this is my color.xml thats sets the color gold for my scoreboard

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="gold">
          <item name="android:textColor">#e6b121</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

I use it in my scoreboard.xml like this

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundsb" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewscores"
        style="@style/gold" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/opnieuw"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:text="Opnieuw spelen" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That wn't change the listitem color, you need to change color of list row..Post your activity code, i'll show how to do that

Comment: a settextcolor is not a possibilty I gues ?

Comment: While populating listview, you'll suplly adapter with its row resource, there you need to supply your custom layout

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><resources><color name="white">#FFFFFF</color><color name="black">#000000</color><color name="green">#008000</color><color name="blue">#0000FF</color>     <color name="red">#FF0000</color> <color name="gray">#858585</color></resources
```

> save the xml file with color.xml in values folder
>   and use that for text view as "android:textColor="@color/blue"